# Construct pandas Dataframe from a dictionary

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I need your help with the following problem. Suppose I have this dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd


dict = {(1, 1, 1): 0.0, (1, 1, 2): 1.0, (1, 2, 1): 0.0, (1, 2, 2): 1.0, (1, 3, 1): 0.0, (1, 3, 2): 0.0, 
        (2, 1, 1): 1.0, (2, 1, 2): 0.0, (2, 2, 1): 0.0, (2, 2, 2): 0.0, (2, 3, 1): 1.0, (2, 3, 2): 0.0, 
        (3, 1, 1): 1.0, (3, 1, 2): 0.0, (3, 2, 1): 0.0, (3, 2, 2): 1.0, (3, 3, 1): 0.0, (3, 3, 2): 0.0}
```

I now need a pandas-df that does the following. The first number in the brackets stands for the person index i. The second for the day t and the third for the shift k worked. A df is now to be created that takes i as the rows and t as the columns. The shifts worked should then be visible in the individual cells, i.e. if the value after the colon is a 1, then this shift is worked, otherwise not. If there is no work on a day, the cell should contain a 0.
The df should look like this according to the dictonary above.

```
Day 1 2 3  
Person                     
1 2 2 0  
2 1 0 1  
3 1 2 0
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Once you created a raw dataframe (1 row per 1 dict entry), you can calculate number of shift worked by multiplying number of shift and work flag.

Then pivot with aggregation:

```
dct = {(1, 1, 1): 0.0, (1, 1, 2): 1.0, (1, 2, 1): 0.0, (1, 2, 2): 1.0, (1, 3, 1): 0.0, (1, 3, 2): 0.0, 
        (2, 1, 1): 1.0, (2, 1, 2): 0.0, (2, 2, 1): 0.0, (2, 2, 2): 0.0, (2, 3, 1): 1.0, (2, 3, 2): 0.0, 
        (3, 1, 1): 1.0, (3, 1, 2): 0.0, (3, 2, 1): 0.0, (3, 2, 2): 1.0, (3, 3, 1): 0.0, (3, 3, 2): 0.0}

df = pd.DataFrame(
    list(dct.keys()),
    columns=["person", "day", "shift"]
)
df["shift_worked"] = df \
    .apply(lambda row: row["shift"] * dct[tuple(row.values)], axis=1) \
    .astype(int)

df.pivot_table(
    index="person",
    columns="day",
    values="shift_worked",
    aggfunc="sum"
)
```

Output:

```
day     1  2  3
person         
1       2  2  0
2       1  0  1
3       1  2  0
```

Comment: This is nice. Instead of adding `df['shift_worked']` consider a boolean series with `m = list(map(bool,dct.values()))`. Then you can just adjust this to: `df[m].pivot_table(index="person", columns="day", values="shift", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [k for k, v in dct.items() if v != 0], 
    columns=['i', 'j', 'k']
).set_index(['i', 'j'])
shifts_worked = df.unstack(['j'])
print(shifts_worked)
```

Output:

```
     k          
j    1    2    3
i               
1  2.0  2.0  NaN
2  1.0  NaN  1.0
3  1.0  2.0  NaN
```

If you want to replace the NaNs with zeros, do this:

```
shifts_worked = shifts_worked.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

A vectorial variant with a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
out = (pd.Series(dic, name='worked')
         .rename_axis(['person', 'day', 'shift'])
         .reset_index()
         .assign(shift=lambda x: x['shift'].where(x['worked'].eq(1), 0))
         .pivot_table(index='person', columns='day',
                      values='shift', aggfunc='sum')
       )
```

Output:

```
day     1  2  3
person         
1       2  2  0
2       1  0  1
3       1  2  0
```

Or, if you don't want to keep the person/day row/column if all values are 0:

```
out = (pd.Series(dic, name='worked')
         .rename_axis(['person', 'day', 'shift'])
         .reset_index()
         .query('worked == 1')
         .pivot_table(index='person', columns='day',
                      values='shift', aggfunc='sum')
       )
```

Example output if person 2 had not worked a single shift:

```
day     1  2
person      
1       2  2
3       1  2
```

Compared to the first approach:

```
day     1  2  3
person         
1       2  2  0
2       0  0  0
3       1  2  0
```

*NB. `aggfunc='sum'` might not be appropriate if a person can have several shifts in a day. It depends if the value in "shift" is quantitative or categorical.*

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```python
index_values = pd.DataFrame(dict.keys(), columns=['i', 't', 'k'])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(index_values)
shifts_worked = pd.Series(dict.values(), index=index, name='Shifts worked')
shifts_worked = shifts_worked.unstack(['t']).groupby('i').sum()
print(shifts_worked)
```

Output:

```
t    1    2    3
i               
1  1.0  1.0  0.0
2  1.0  0.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  0.0
```

B.t.w you shouldn't use the name `'dict'` as a variable because `dict` is a built-in function.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood.  This calculates the 'number of shifts worked' not the 'id number of the shift worked'.  Sorry.